# .click function working without arguments, but not working with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this function which was working:

```
$('#buttFurniture').click(onFilterCLick);
```

but then i decided to add some argument to the function and it stopped working:

```
$('#buttFurniture').click(onFilterCLick(arrOutput, arrFurniture));
```

full function:

```
function onFilterCLick(arrFull,arrCurrent) {
    $('#buttFurniture').css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
    $('#buttCars').css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
    $('#buttGames').css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
    $('#buttFurniture').css("color", "black");
    $('#buttCars').css("color", "black");
    $('#buttGames').css("color", "black");

    $(this).css("background-color", "#656565");
    $(this).css("color", "white");

    if (jQuery.inArray(arrCurrent[0], arrFull)) {
        console.log("asdasd");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use anonymous function. `$('#buttFurniture').click(function() { onFilterCLick(arrOutput, arrFurniture)});`

Answer (score 5):

**The solution:** Use bind to assign arguments when passing functions:

```
 $('#buttFurniture').click(onFilterCLick.bind($('#buttFurniture'), arrOutput, arrFurniture));
```

**Explanation:** In javascript, functions are what's known as first class objects - that means they can be passed around as variables, like other primitives (numbers, booleans etc.), but also as *arguments to functions*.

In this regard, it's important to note a key difference in passing a function as a variable, and invoking a function. For example, consider the following function:

```
var myFunc = function () {
    return 0;
}
```

Now, note the difference between these two statements:

```
typeof myFunc // "function"
typeof myFunc() // "number"
```

As you can see, the first is a reference to the function itself, and the second is the invocation of that function - a subtle but key difference.

Your click handler expects a **function** as it's argument, and NOT a **function invocation** (or the result of a function being called). That's why you must use bind: bind allows you to pass the *function itself*, but also gives you the ability to pre-fill the arguments of the function you're passing.

In brief, the `bind()` function (in your case) takes 3 arguments - the first argument, in every `bind()` function, is the `this` parameter - setting `this` to your selected element is necessary, so that your `$(this)` invocation has the right context. The other arguments are where you pre-fill the rest of your function's parameters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Tushar I'm not sure of your point. This solves the OPs problem and is neater than wrapping a named function call in an anonymous function (IMO)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is not readable and confusing than using anonymous function.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you notice that OP is using $(this) inside onFilterCLick function that's why OP is getting problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Why to use $('#buttFurniture') instead you can pass an argument then use that to refer this... how about ? `onFilterCLick.bind(this, arrOutput, arrFurniture)` and inside the function use `$(this)`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal It didn't work because in that scope, `this` referred to the window object. I edited it to just explicitly call the correct element again. All done now

Comment: @Jonathan I have also posted my answer which might be good way to do rather than using `$('#buttFurniture')` inside `bind()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback function of click event to call another function with parameter.

```
$('#buttFurniture').click(function () {
    onFilterCLick(arrOutput, arrFurniture)
});
```

Comment: Yes, without clicking #buttFurniture, the button procs 2 times

Comment: actually everything is working perfectly with the console, it doesn't proc at all

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the `.bind(null,func_arguments)` method as described by @JonathanBrooks when you don't use the `$(this)` inside the function definition since `this` would refer to `window` object.

However, if you want to select the context as 'this' then I would recommend you to use like this:

```
function onFilterCLick(elem,arrFull,arrCurrent) {
  //now you can use elem to refer $(this)
  elem.css("background-color", "#656565");
}
```

And use the anonymous function for the click event like this:

```
$('#buttFurniture').click(function(){
    onFilterCLick($(this),arrOutput,arrFurniture);
});
```

A working code example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qzgdcv60/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're calling 
`onFilterCLick(arrOutput, arrFurniture)`  in `$('#buttFurniture').click(onFilterCLick(arrOutput, arrFurniture));`
not passing `onFilterCLick` as handler for click event.

Comment: @murloc Tushar gave the answer in the comment

Comment: well, it doesn't work that is not the problem.. well I will just have to go around it

Answer (score 0):

In case if **#buttFurniture** is generated after the DOM is ready

```
function onFilterCLick(arrOutput, arrFurniture) {
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).toggleClass('red-border');
};

$('#buttFurniture').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var holder = onFilterCLick.bind(this); 
    holder('argOne', 'argTwo');
});
```

`.bind(this)` will override `this` inside function scope if you want to select same element that you clicked.

#### UPDATE

I've updated the example, sorry for untested code, here is the [fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/roth/jtshrzr3/1/)
also read [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/) for better bind understanding ;)

This also will work.

```
var holder = onFilterCLick.bind(this, 'argOne', 'argTwo'); 
holder();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: onFilterCLick will be undefined.

Comment: did you test your code? this doesn't work. this throws an error `undefined`

Comment: I've updated my answer, now the example should work.