# Click event added to appended html; element not working as anticipated

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK I am sure I am doing something simple fundamentally wrong but am unable to resolve this issue on my own. I have tried googling and searching this forum and reading through the relevant parts of the jquery documentation.

If you need any further information please let me know. Many thanks in advance.

**What I am trying to do:**

I have a table showing details of various tests at the bottom of which I have a button to ad a new test. As each test comprises several rows of the table I have a template in a hidden div which I have cloned and appended to the live table. I am the using jquery to add appropriate classes and ids based on a variable integer for the sake of uniqueness. I am also attempting to add a click event to an image within one of the table cell to delete the rows relating to that particular test.

**My current function**

```
function newTest(sampleID){
    var testID = $("#testCount").val();
    $("#newTest tr").clone(true)
        .addClass("test"+testID)
        .appendTo("#testsTable"+sampleID);
    $(".newdelbox:first")
        .attr("id","testDelete"+testID)
        .addClass("delbox")
        .removeClass("newdelbox");
    $(".test"+testID).on('click',"#testDelete"+testID,delSample(testID));
    testID++;
    $("#testCount").val(testID);
}
```

**What I need to happen**

Function to be called when image is clicked.

**What is happening**

Function is called only when script is assigned (not clicked). Function will not subsequently run when clicked. I am seeing no errors within the console.

**What I have tried**

chained to preceeding code:

```
.click(delSample(testID));
.on("click",delSample(testID));
.bind("click",delSample(testID));
```

As new line within function:

```
$(".test"+testID).on('click',"#testDelete"+testID,delSample(testID));
document.getElementById("testDelete"+testID).onclick(delSample(testID));
document.getElementById("testDelete"+testID).addEventListener("click",delSample(testID),false);
```

Comment: `.on("click",delSample(testID));` ==> `.on("click", function() { delSample(testID) });`

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542611/click-function-working-without-arguments-but-not-working-with-arguments/33543783#33543783

Comment: Thanks so much, this was the problem exactly. I was unaware of the difference between passing a function and invoking a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 .click(function(){
  delSample(testID);
  });
```

OR

```
.on("click",function(){
   delSample(testID);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know of your html but i supose something like

```
.on("click",function(){
   var current_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
   delSample(current_id);
});
```

just locate your id